# segmentation fault on inserting vector elements in a vector<vector>

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, segmentation-fault, computer-science

In the constructor of a class called `Stamp` have two vectors:

- `vector<double> data` has a size of `data.size()`
- `vector<vector <double>> collectedData` has a size of [nsamples][data.size()/nsamples]

I need to cycle them in order to have something like this:

- `collectedData[0][0->nsamples]` has the first "nsamples" elements of `data`
- 'collectedData[1][0->nsamples]' has the second "nsamples" elements of `data`
- ...
- `'collectedData[i][0->nsamples]`' has the i'th "nsamples" elements of `data` (and '0' if I went over `data.size()`)

This is the C++ code I'm trying, but I receive a segmentation fault. And I don't understand if it is an algorithmic problem, or a wrong usage of `vector` problem:

```
Stamp(vector<double> data, int nsamples) : data(data), nsamples(nsamples){
        long ll = data.size()/nsamples;
        int row;

        //Reserve space in collectedData:
        collectedData.reserve(nsamples);
        for (int i=0;i<nsamples;i++){
            collectedData[i].reserve(ll);
        }

        for (int i=0;i<=data.size();i+=nsamples){
     
            for (int j=0;(j<=nsamples)&&((row*i)<data.size());j++){
                collectedData[i].push_back(data[i]);
            }
            row++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `i<=data.size()` [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) here.

Comment: `.reserve(...)`  is not the same as `.resize()` on a `std::vector`. In the first loop, `collectedData[i]` cannot return a reference to a valid inner vector object because it has not been constructed yet. Long story short: change the first `reserve` into a `resize`.

Comment: thanks @MikeCAT, still giving "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" after one cycle

Comment: `collectedData.reserve(nsamples);` does not ensure that there are `nsamples` elements, only that there is enough space for them (i.e. `collectedData` still has the same `size()`, but possibly a different `capacity()`). You want `resize`.

Comment: You forgot to initalize `row`.

Comment: Apart from the obvious glitch, there are a few other issues with your question. In particular, it lacks a [mcve]. Also, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the [`reserve()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) function only reserves space without actualy adding elements. You should use [`resize()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) to add (or remove) elements.

Secondly, the condition `i<=data.size()` in the `for` loop is wrong. You cannot use `data[data.size()]`. It should be `i<data.size()`.

Thirdly, there doesn't seem a guarantee that `data.size() <= nsamples`, so you should add elements again not to cause out-of-range access by `collectedData[i]` in the second `for` loop.

Finally, as @molbdnilo pointed out in the comment, the value of non-static local variable `row` is used without initialization. You should set some proper value to the variable before using that.

```
Stamp(vector<double> data, int nsamples) : data(data), nsamples(nsamples){
        long ll = data.size()/nsamples;
        int row = 0; // initialize row

        //Reserve space in collectedData:
        if (collectedData.size() < nsamples){
            collectedData.resize(nsamples); // use resize() to add elements
        }
        if (collectedData.size() < data.size()){
            collectedData.resize(data.size()); // use resize() again to allocate enough size
        }
        for (int i=0;i<nsamples;i++){
            collectedData[i].reserve(ll); // using reserve() here because elements are added via push_back() later
        }

        for (int i=0;i<data.size();i+=nsamples){ // use correct condition
     
            for (int j=0;(j<=nsamples)&&((row*i)<data.size());j++){
                collectedData[i].push_back(data[i]);
            }
            row++;
        }
    }
```